# How to convert class to decodable Json like @SerializedName in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I need create a two class to decode json response, like @SerializedName in Kotlin, like this:

```
class PixHistoryResponse(
    @SerializedName("cadastro")
    var createdAt: String = "",
    @SerializedName("status")
    var status: String = "",
    @SerializedName("valor")
    var finalAmount: String = "",
    @SerializedName("timeline")
    var history: MutableList<PixTimelineResponse> = mutableListOf(),


@Keep
class PixTimelineResponse(
    @SerializedName("cadastro")
    var date: String = "",
    @SerializedName("status")
    var event: String = "",
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I think you should use `struct` for modeling data, because it's a value type. Should not use reference type like `class`.

```
struct PixHistoryResponse: Decodable {
    var createdAt: String = ""
    var finalAmount: String = "",
    var history: [PixTimelineResponse] = []

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case createdAt = "cadastro"
        case finalAmount = "valor"
        case hisotry = "timeline"
    }
}

struct PixTimelineResponse: Decodable {
    var date: String = ""
    var event: String = ""
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "cadastro"
        case event = "status"
    }
}
```